# Azure API Management: rewrite-uri policy do not work in versioned API

Tags: azure-api-management

I have an backend API, say:

```
GET https://bk.my.com/api/store/goods
```

and I use Azure API management as proxy. here is the main settings for my api "My Test API"

```
Web Service URL:  https://bk.my.com/
API URL suffix :  
                  Base URL
                  https://bk-xxx.azure-api.net
```

add API operation, here is the operation settings (Frontend, I only use this, other settings keep default)

```
Display Name:   Get all goods
Name        :   get-all-goods
URL         :   GET  /api/store/goods
```

it works. since

```
https://bk-xxx.azure-api.net/api/store/goods => https://bk.my.com/api/store/goods
```

now I need to add a new version for this API. Here is the v2 api in the backend.

```
GET https://bk.my.com/api/v2/store/goods
```

I create a new version api name 'v2' by using header classification

```
 GET https://bk-xxx.azure-api.net/[operation]
 api-version: v2
```

so in "My Test API", there are 2 versions

```
>My Test API       <operation>         <frontend>            <inbound>
    Original    ->  get-all-goods -> GET /api/store/goods

    v2          ->  get-all-goods -> GET /api/store/goods    <inbound>
                                                                <base />
                                                                <rewrite-uri template="/api/v2/store/goods" />
                                                              </inbound>
```

when I test v2 api, but it does't work, trace says:

```
configuration (0 ms)
{
    "message": "Unable to identify Api or Operation for this request. Responding to the caller with 404 Resource Not Found."
}
```

then I try to fix v2 api operation by removing rewrite-uri

```
>My Test API       <operation>         <frontend>            <inbound>
    Original    ->  get-all-goods -> GET /api/store/goods

    v2          ->  get-all-goods -> GET /api/v2/store/goods
```

it works now.

so My question is why rewrite-uri do not work ?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I understand your question but what are you trying to do with this rewrite -url  ""  ?
Do you want to send the api request to this url? I mean, is this your backend-url?

If so then you can use set backe-end policy.